# jQuery - hide label & radio after checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need to hide a label & radio button after a checkbox was checked a **page before**. I need this to hide a radio button in a order process. The problem is that the checkbox and the label&radio are not at the same page.

This is my checkbox:

```
<input id="coupon" class="checkbox" name="coupon" value="yes" type="checkbox">
```

And this are the two elements I want to hide at the next page:

```
<input id="payment_paypal_1" class="radio" name="payment_paypal" value="2" required="" type="radio">
<label id="payment_paypal_2" for="payment_paypal">PayPal</label>
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: This is not solvable using jQuery and javascript alone. Tell your programming language, and show the code which forwards to next page.

Comment: Easiest way: Use PHP for handling a GET-Request, though I would not suggest this. Use a PHP Session variable for passing values would be a better option. Others include Ajax with Post and a database and stuff...

Comment: you can use local storage

Comment: You can send a parameter in the URL, and get it with your JavaScript code.

Comment: You can send the coupon as checked or not as an URL parameter to the next page. From the next page; load the parameters and locate whether the coupon parameter is there or not.

Comment: Ok I changed the page a little and now I have the two elements on the same page. Has anybody an idea how to hide the two elements with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If on the same page then using jquery, you can do it like this -

```
            $("#coupon").click(function() {                   
                if ($(this).prop('checked')===true){ 
                    console.log("checked") ;
                    $('#payment_paypal_1').hide();
                    $('#payment_paypal_2').hide();
                }
                else {
                   console.log(" un checked") ;  
                   $('#payment_paypal_1').show();
                   $('#payment_paypal_2').show();
                }
            });
```